# Unit Tesing directives in Angular without TestBed & Component

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I did write a Unit Testing for a directive and it works but I wanted to ask if I can test it without component and TestBed.
What can I here change or what can I improve?
What is the idea to create a TestComponent and the idea of TestBed

Here it is the code of the directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][endOfSeasonValidation]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => EndOfSeasonValidationDirective),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class EndOfSeasonValidationDirective extends AbstractValidatorDirective {
  @Input('beginDate')
  public beginDate: Date | null;

  @Input('startOfSeason')
  public startOfSeason: number | null;

  public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const endOfSeason = control.value;

    if (!endOfSeason || !this.startOfSeason || !this.beginDate) {
      return null;
    }

    if (
      endOfSeason === this.startOfSeason ||
      endOfSeason + (endOfSeason < this.startOfSeason ? 12 : 0) - this.startOfSeason === 11
    ) {
      return { isInvalid: true };
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

And here it is the code of unit testing

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form>
      <select
        endOfSeasonValidation
        [ngModel]="endOfSeason"
        name="endOfSeason"
        [beginDate]="beginDate"
        [startOfSeason]="startOfSeason"
      ></select>
    </form>
  `,
})
class EndOfSeasonValidationTestComponent {
  public beginDate = new Date('2020-01-16');
  public startOfSeason: number | null;
  public endOfSeason: number | null;
  @ViewChild(NgForm, { static: true })
  public form: NgForm;
}
describe('EndOfSeasonValidationDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EndOfSeasonValidationTestComponent>;
  let form: NgForm;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        EndOfSeasonValidationTestComponent,
        EndOfSeasonValidationDirective,
        DateAccessorPluginDirective,
        SelectAccessorDirective,
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EndOfSeasonValidationTestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    form = fixture.componentInstance.form;
  });
  it('should not validate if beginDate or startOfSeason or endOfSeason are not given', async () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.beginDate = new Date('2020-01-01');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(form.valid).toBeTruthy();
    expect(form.errors).toBeFalsy();
  });
  it('should validate if startOfSeason and endOfSeason are equal', async () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.beginDate = new Date('2020-12-02');
    fixture.componentInstance.startOfSeason = 2;
    fixture.componentInstance.endOfSeason = 2;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.form.invalid).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#attribute-directive-testing) correct way to test `Directive` - is to use some component (TestComponent or not).
Answers to your questions:

1. You can test your directive simply creating instance until it hasn't DI dependencies.

```
const dir = new EndOfSeasonValidationDirective();
... some changes with inputs
expect(dir.validate()).toEqual({isInvalid: true})
```

But a better way to test it in more real environment - using in pair with some component. So idea to create a TestComponent is to provide more real environment (run all of the angular internal gears under the hood) for your unit test.

1. `TestBed` is a helper tool to resolve angular DI dependencies and create testing module.
2. I think your test is good, but you can improve it by covering it up to 100%. All cases and `If` statements should be tested.

**UPD** 
Totally you should cover these cases:

1. should not validate if endOfSeason is not provided
2. should not validate if startOfSeason is not provided
3. should not validate if beginDate is not provided
4. should validate if startOfSeason and endOfSeason are equal
5. should validate if (I don't know what does this expression means in business words) endOfSeason + (endOfSeason < this.startOfSeason ? 12 : 0) - this.startOfSeason === 11

After writing these tests your coverage will be 100% for this directive, all cases will be tested. You can run it for example in `Webstorm` or `Intellij IDEA` by pressing `Run with Coverage` button.

Comment: Can you give me a help on this how to test all cases and If statementsc?

Comment: Can you provide a code that I can make this test working without component and TestBed ?

Comment: I have approved your answer but i need a little help on the last question what I have asked you.